# Customize system notification (android) for connected VPN in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications

i have created a vpn application using flutter. i want to custmize the android notifcation which indicates VPN connected,  currently i am getting this notification

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications? It has a pretty good documentation which can help you achieve the solution.